# Firebase too slow to load for a tile-based game

Tags: swift, firebase

I'm building a 2d tile-based game for iOS with swift and Firebase. Because the world is large, I've designed it so that I only subscribe to the tiles that are on screen. That is, instead of adding listeners for all 10,000x10,000 tiles, I add them to just the tiles on screen. As the player moves, I de-register the old listeners and register the new ones. I've added a bit of a buffer zone around the edge of the screen, in the hopes that everything will be sufficiently loaded by the time it moves on screen. Unfortunately, there is often significant enough lag from Firebase that this strategy simply isn't working. On sub-optimal internet connections, it's possible to keep walking into the "unloaded world," taking several seconds at times to load the missing tiles.

Here's the thing, though: other MMO iOS games on the same connection and same device work fine. It's not a terrible connection. Which makes me suspect my implementation, or Firebase itself is at fault.

Fundamentally I'm waiting on the "load once" event for about 20 tiles each time I take a step. A step takes about 1/4 of a second, so each second I'm requesting about 100 items from Firebase. I can't think of a better way, though. Firebase documentation suggests that this should not be a problem, since it's all one socket connection. I could "bucket" the objects into, say, 10x10 blocks which would mean that I'd subscribe to fewer objects, but this would also be more wasteful in terms of total data transfer. If the socket connection is truly optimized, total data transfer should be the only bottleneck, implying this strategy would be wrong.

### *edit*

Here's a video showing how it works. The buffer-size has been reduced to `-1`, so that you can easily see the edges of the screen and the tiles loading and unloading. Near the end of the video, lag strikes and I wander into the emptiness. I opened up another game and it loaded almost instantly. http://forevermaze.inzania.com/videos/FirebaseLag.mov (*n.b., I ended the recording before the screen loaded again. It never fails to load, so it's not as if the code is failing to work. It's pure lag.*)

Here is the code I'm using to load the tiles. It's called once for each tile. As I said, this means that this code is called about 20 times per step, in parallel. All other apps are running at a fine speed with no lag. I'm on a MiFi with LTE connectivity in Tokyo, so it's a solid connection.

```
  /**
   * Given a path to a firebase object, get the snapshot with a timeout.
   */
  static func loadSnapshot(firebasePath: String!) -> Promise<FDataSnapshot?> {
    let (promise, fulfill, _) = Promise<FDataSnapshot?>.pendingPromise()
    let connection = Firebase(url: Config.firebaseUrl + firebasePath)
    connection.observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in
      if !promise.resolved {
        fulfill(snapshot)
      }
    })
    after(Config.timeout).then { () -> Void in
      if !promise.resolved {
        DDLogWarn("[TIMEOUT] [FIREBASE-READ] \(firebasePath)")
        fulfill(nil)
        //reject(Errors.network)
      }
    }
    return promise
  }
```

The tiles reside at `[ROOT]/tiles/[X]x[Y]`. Most tiles contain very little data, but if there are objects on that tile (i.e., other players) those are stored. Here's a screenshot from Firebase:
[image]

### *edit2*

Per request, I've recreated this issue very simply. Here is a 100-line `XCTestCase` class: http://forevermaze.com/code/LagTests.swift

Usage:

1. Drop the file into your Swift project (it should be stand-alone, requiring only Firebase)
2. Change the value of `firebaseUrl` to your root URL (i.e., `https://MyProject.firebaseio.com`)
3. Run the `testSetupDatabase()` function test once to setup the initial state of the database
4. Run the `testWalking()` function to test the lag. This is the main test. It will fail if any tile takes longer than 2 seconds to load.

I've tried this test on several different connections. A top-notch office connection passes with no problem, but even a high-end LTE or MiFi connection fails. `2 seconds` is already a *very* long timeout, since it implies that I need to have a `10 tile` buffer zone (0.2 seconds * 10 tiles = 2 seconds). Here's some output when I'm connected to a LTE connection, showing that it took nearly 10 seconds (!!) to load a tile:
`error: -[ForeverMazeTests.LagTests testWalking] : XCTAssertTrue failed - Tile 2x20 took 9.50058007240295`

Comment: Thanks for the clear description of your goal. But it is a pretty broad topic. Without boiling it down a bit, it'll be difficult to help much. Can you reduce the problem to a specific snippet of code, a sample of your data structure and a question about the two?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen thanks. I've added a bunch of additional info, including a video, code snippets, and a screenshot from my Firebase data tree.

Comment: FYI The video won't play for me; perhaps it's corrupted.

Comment: @jtbandes sorry, I was a bit fast on the `save edit` button. It just finished uploading now, please try again (I tested and it works for me).

Comment: That code looks fine and the data structure looks small enough. So it's more likely that something else in the context of this snippet is causing the slowdown. Can you reduce the program to a minimum (but complete) that reproduces the problem, so that somebody can run and reproduce the problem locally? It would in that case also help if you include the JSON as text, instead of a screenshot.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I've created a very simple stand-alone 100 line `XCTestCase` class that regularly fails. See the `edit2` in my question for download and for usage instructions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran a few tests and the loading completes in 15-20 seconds when I test over a 3G connection. Over my regular connection it takes 1-2 seconds, so the difference is likely purely based on bandwidth.

I rewrote your test case into a JavaScript version, because I had a hard time figuring out what's going on. Find mine here: http://jsbin.com/dijiba/edit?js,console

```
var ref = new Firebase(URL);
var tilesPerStep = 20;
var stepsToTake = 100;

function testWalking() {
  var startTime = Date.now();
  var promises = [];
  for (var x=0; x < stepsToTake; x++) {
    promises.push(testStep(x));
  }
  Promise.all(promises).then(function() {
    console.log('All '+promises.length+' steps done in '+(Date.now()-startTime)+'ms');
  });
}

function testStep(x) {
  var result = new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
    var tiles = ref.child("/tiles_test");
    var loading = 0;
    var startTime = Date.now();
    console.log('Start loading step '+x);

    for (var y=0; y < tilesPerStep; y++) {
      loading ++;
      tiles.child(x+'x'+y).once('value', function(snapshot) {
        var time = Date.now() - startTime;
        loading--;
        if (loading === 0) {
          console.log('Step '+x+' took '+(Date.now()-startTime)+'ms');
          resolve(Date.now() - startTime);
        }
      });
    }
  });
  return result;
}

testWalking();
```

The biggest difference is that I don't delay starting any of the loading and I don't fail for a specific tile. I think that last bit is why your tests are failing.

All loading from Firebase happens asynchronously, but all requests are going through the same connection. When you start loading, you are queueing up a lot of requests. This timing is skewed by "preceding requests that haven't been fulfilled yet".

This is a sample of a test run with just 10 steps:

```
"Start loading step 0"
"Start loading step 1"
"Start loading step 2"
"Start loading step 3"
"Start loading step 4"
"Start loading step 5"
"Start loading step 6"
"Start loading step 7"
"Start loading step 8"
"Start loading step 9"
"Step 0 took 7930ms"
"Step 1 took 7929ms"
"Step 2 took 7948ms"
"Step 3 took 8594ms"
"Step 4 took 8669ms"
"Step 5 took 9141ms"
"Step 6 took 9851ms"
"Step 7 took 10365ms"
"Step 8 took 10425ms"
"Step 9 took 11520ms"
"All 10 steps done in 11579ms"
```

You'll probably note that the time taken for each step does not add up to the time taken for all steps combined. Essentially you are starting each request while there are still requests in the pipeline. This is the most efficient way of loading these items, but it does mean that you'll need to measure performance differently.

Essentially all steps **start** at almost the same time. Then you're waiting for the first response (which is in the above case includes establishing a WebSocket connection from the client to the correct Firebase server) and after that the responses come in reasonable intervals (given that there are 20 requests per step).

All of this is very interesting, but it doesn't solve your problem of course. I would recommend that you model your data into screen-sized buckets. So instead of having each tile separate, store every 10x10 tiles in a "bucket". You'll reduce the overhead of each separate request and only need to request at most one bucket for every 10 steps.

### Update

I'm pretty sure we're just debugging multiple artifacts of your benchmark approach. If I update the code to this:

```
func testWalking() {
    let expectation = expectationWithDescription("Load tiles")
    let maxTime = self.timeLimit + self.stepTime * Double(stepsToTake)

    let startTime = NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970

    for (var x=0; x<stepsToTake; x++) {
        let delay = Double(x) * stepTime
        let data = ["x":x, "ex": expectation]
        stepsRemaining++
        NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0, target: self, selector: Selector("testStep:"), userInfo: data, repeats: false)
    }
    waitForExpectationsWithTimeout(maxTime) { error in
        let time = NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970 - startTime
        print("Completed loading after \(time)")
        if error != nil {
            print("Error: \(error!.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
}

/**
* Helper function to test a single step (executes `tilesPerStep` number of tile loads)
*/
func testStep(timer : NSTimer) {
    let tiles = Firebase(url: firebaseUrl).childByAppendingPath("/tiles_test")
    let data = timer.userInfo as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>
    let x = data["x"] as! Int
    let expectation = data["ex"] as! XCTestExpectation
    var loading = 0
    print("Start loading \(x)")

    for (var y=0; y<tilesPerStep; y++) {
        loading++
        tiles.childByAppendingPath("\(x)x\(y)").observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in
            loading--
            if loading == 0 {
                print("Done loading \(x)")
                self.stepsRemaining--
                if self.stepsRemaining == 0 {
                    expectation.fulfill()
                }
            }
        })
    }
}
```

It completes the entire loading in less than 2 seconds over a high-speed network, over 3G it takes between 15 and 25 seconds.

But my recommendation of modeling at a level of more than each single tile remains.

Comment: I'm a bit confused about your comment re: artifacts in my approach. If you look at my code, you'll notice the `XCAssertTrue` code is run on a per-step basis. That is, even though there is a delay in firing each step, the expectations are calculated with the assertion that no step takes more than 1/5 of a second (*not* that the entire step sequence takes a certain amount of time; I think you may be confused by the `waitForExpectationsWithTimeout` function, which is really more of a "final timeout" and not relevant to the individual tests). I don't care about total time, just step-time.

Comment: You're queueing up 100 steps of 20 reads each to a database that sequentially handles them (and pipelines them on the wire). Unless you properly serialize the requests (starting each next step after the previous one is finished or throttling the request rate to match the response rate), the later steps are guaranteed to take longer, since the database is still processing requests from the steps before it.

Comment: I added a example of "properly serialized requests" to the [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/dijiba/edit?js,console)(in a `testWalking2()` method). Each step now only starts after the previous one is finished. Each step (of 20 reads) takes between 1 and 2 seconds now over 3G, with the total run (of 100 steps) taking 181 seconds. So, even though the total time is a lot higher than the 20 seconds I got earlier, the measurement of each step is now accurate, since steps are no longer impacted by pending requests from earlier steps.

Comment: Your code is fundamentally different, though. By only taking a second step after the first step completes, it means that the player cannot walk smoothly. Take a look at my video. Imagine if the first step took 0.3 seconds to complete. It would mean that the player would be frozen for 0.1 seconds until the second step could fire. If any one tile lagged significantly (like with my 10 second example), it'd freeze the whole game.

Comment: I added both types of code: `testWalking()` is the same as yours, but with the timing removed. `testWalking2()` executes the steps one after the other. But I think we've spent enough time discussing micro-optimizations: the proper solution is to load the tiles in chunks, instead of per tile.

Comment: I just realized that the "bucketing" solution is not going to work. Here's why: each tile can have objects on the tile. Per the Firebase recommendations, I have a double-reference, such that the tile contains a reference to the object IDs it contains (see my screenshot). It's entirely feasible that every tile has one or more objects on it. This means that even if I optimize tiles into buckets, I still need to make at least one extra Firebase load call for every object on that tile. I can't bucket the objects themselves, since their paths cannot be location-dependent. Any suggestions?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99861/discussion-between-zane-claes-and-frank-van-puffelen).